# Getting a Button to Apply to an Imported Module Automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I went through the painstaking process (for a rookie such as myself) of building a template,writing a macro to get it to export certain elements to different workbooks in a directory, and distributing modules and user forms to those different workbooks.

My problem is that the buttons in my output templates still refer to macros in my source workbook (rather than the modules I've Imported) and I'm wondering how I can get it to automatically break this link and apply the imported code to the new button.

If anyone could point me in the direction of a general solution I'd be eternally grateful.

Thanks

Comment: By `export certain elements`, are you exporting sheets and saves it as another workbook? I assume you do it by code? Please post it?

Answer (score 0):

1. When assigning macros using <kbd>[Alt]</kbd> + <kbd>[F8]</kbd> (Pop up the Macro window - Alternatively, Click 'Macros' in 'Developer' tab)
2. There is an option (Macros in: ), please choose "This Workbook" instead of "All Open Workbooks" and you would be able to assign right macro that you created to the button.

[image: Macro Window - Microsoft Excel]